# PowerShell, loop a task at fixed times (without Start-Sleep / Start-Job / Start-Process)

Tags: powershell, for-loop, schedule

I can easily loop through a task every minute for 24 hours as follows:

```
for($i = 0; $i -lt 1440; $i++){
    # do task here ...
    Start-Sleep 60
}
```

However, the task can take from 1 second to 20 seconds, meaning that the Start-Sleep will get staggered.

How can I tell the loop to execute at an exact set time, such as say, at exactly 8 seconds past every minute (regardless of how long the task takes)?

I would prefer not to spawn the task off to a `Start-Job` or `Start-Process` as the task relies on a number of things earlier in the script and it would be cumbersome to have to have those things all defined within the job. I don't want the complexity of scheduled tasks either, as hopefully this can be controllable from a simple loop?

Comment: Why not use a scheduled task for this? What is the "complexity" you're trying to avoid and why?

Comment: Well, to me, it feels awkward when I'm just trying to loop some tasks to have to handle scheduled tasks. Maybe for you, they are simple, but I guess it's like Filewatchers, I've never been able to get them to play nice, so I just construct my own loops to watch files, and that seems a ton more reliable. I look on scheduled tasks in the same way. Additionally, if I can do this in a simple loop, it's automatically cross platform and I can use it on Linux without changing anything really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to measure the processing time and subtract this value from your sleep value, e.g.:

```
$sleep = 60
for($i = 0; $i -lt 1440; $i++){
    $processingTime = measure-command {# do task here ...}
    $newSleep = $sleep - $processingTime.totalSeconds
    If ($newSleep -lt 0){
        $newSleep = 0
    }
    Start-Sleep $newSleep
}
```

Comment: This is great Toni. It is conceivable that a task could overrun, maybe go to 3 minutes, in which case, my overall loop 1440 steps would run longer than 24 hours. I guess I could collect a `Get-Date` before entering the loop, then in the loop test if it has gone over 24 hours, and if so `break` out of the loop, then it will never go past the solid 24 hour mark. Quite a solid solution, thanks.

Comment: you could also take a look at ```$sw = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()```